# CreateJS EaselJS - inconsistent rotation treatment of different shapes

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

Here's a fiddle animation that shows this inconsistency in the way EaselJS rotates shapes:

[fiddle me this](https://jsfiddle.net/djdcgp9m/)

A star, circle, rectangle, and rounded rectangle are created and placed at the exact same x,y location

```
    rect.x = star.x = circle.x = rrect.x = stage.canvas.width  / 2;
    rect.y = star.y = circle.y = rrect.y = stage.canvas.height / 2;
```

They are then rotated in the exact same manner in the tick loop:

```
rect.rotation = circle.rotation = rrect.rotation = star.rotation += 1;
```

All shapes have the same regX and regY value (zero).

The result, as can be seen in the fiddle, shows some objects with centered rotation and others with offset rotation.

To me this seems messy and confusing, but if anyone can help and correct the way I'm looking at this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is just due to how the Canvas APIs work. Rectangles and arcs draw from the top left, whereas circles and polystars draw from the center.

I have modified your fiddle to adjust the regX and regY (like you unused rect1 shape). You can also adjust the x/y in the negative when drawing top-left shapes.

```
// Offset your regX/Y
shape.graphics.beginStroke("#00f").drawRect(0,0,40,40);
shape.regX = shape.regY = 20;

// Offset your draw operations' center point. This is my usual approach
shape.graphics.beginStroke("#f00").drawRect(-20,-20,40,40);
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/djdcgp9m/2/